# Strange std::cout behaviour with const char*

Tags: c++, string, iostream, cout, c-strings

I have a method which returns a string to display as an error message. Depending on where this error occurs in the program, I might add a bit more of an explanation to the error message before displaying it.

```
string errorMessage() {
    return "this is an error";
}

// somewhere in the program...
const char* message = ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str();
cout << message << endl;
```

(I am storing the message as a const char* since I will actually provide this error to another method which accepts const char* arguments)

At this point it outputs garbage (unprintable characters on the console).

So I played with it and found that if instead I do:

```
// somewhere in the program...
const char* message = ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str();
cout << ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str() << endl << message << endl;
```

then it displays the message correctly twice.

Why does providing the extra argument to `cout` cause it to work as I intended?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage())` is a **temporary** `std::string`. That means, after the  statement is finished, it's lifetime has ended.

```
cout << ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str() << endl
```

works because at the point `std::cout` uses the `std::string` its lifetime hasn't ended yet. The

```
<< message
```

part is undefined behavior, though. Sheer luck it works.

To fix the problem, you need to extend the `std::string`'s lifetime with either a `const std::string&` or, since C++11, a `std::string&&`:

```
const std::string&  str_const_ref = "Some extra info \n" + errorMessage();
std::string&& str_rvalue = "Some extra info \n" + errorMessage();
```

Now you can operate on them as you want to.

Another way is to

```
std::string str = "Some extra info \n" + errorMessage();
```

However, if the compiler doesn't do some [Return Value Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization), this will lead to a constructor **and** a copy constructor (< C++11, **very bad**) or move constructor (>= C++11, better, but unnecessary) getting executed.

---

BTW, this exact issue is even covered in "The C++ Programming Language" 4<sup>th</sup> Edition!

In §10.3.4 "Temporary Objects", Mr Stroustrup writes:

> The standard-library string has a member `c_str()` (§36.3) that returns a C-style pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters
>   (§2.2.5, §43.4). Also, the operator `+` is defined to mean string
>   concatenation. These are useful facilities for strings. However, in
>   combination they can cause obscure problems. For example:
>
> ```
> void f(string& s1, string& s2, string& s3) {
>     const char* cs = (s1+s2).c_str();
>     cout << cs;
>     if (strlen(cs=(s2+s3).c_str())<8 && cs[0]=='a') {
>         // cs used here
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [...] A temporary string object is created to hold `s1+s2`. Next, a pointer
>   to a C-style string is extracted from that object. Then – at the end of
>   the expression – the temporary object is deleted. However, the C-
>   style string returned by `c_str()` was allocated as part of the temporary
>   object holding `s1+s2`, and that storage is not guaranteed to exist after
>   that temporary is destroyed. Consequently, `cs` points to deallocated
>   storage. The output operation `cout<<cs` might work as expected, but
>   that would be sheer luck. A compiler can detect and warn against
>   many variants of this problem.
>   The problem with the `if`-statement is a bit more subtle. The
>   condition will work as expected because the full expression in which
>   the temporary holding `s2+s3` is created is the condition itself.
>   However, that temporary is destroyed before the controlled statement
>   is entered, so any use of `cs` there is not guaranteed to work.

So, do not worry about your C++ skills. Even the C++ bible explains it. ;-)

Comment: Ah this makes sense. It was the fact that it always worked in one case and never in the other that really threw me

Comment: @rbennett485 Something like this is almost always undefined behavior or a misplaced macro. :-)

Comment: when you say 'something like this' you mean a program that sometimes works as intended and sometimes not?

Comment: @rbennett485 Yup. Undefined behavior enables the machine to do everything. Work, not work, segfault, etc.

Comment: `("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage())` does not have scope because it has no name. Don't confuse scope (a compile-time property of names) with lifetime (a run-time property of objects).

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah, sorry. I was looking for the right word and thought "scope'll do it." Will edit that.

Answer (score 4):

```
const char* message = ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str();
cout << message << endl;
```

`errorMessage()` returns a temporary `std::string` object
Concatenating with `"Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()` creates another temporary object.
Taking c_str of it returns a pointer to its internal buffer (not a copy).
And then the temporary object is deleted, and the pointer invalid.
Everything else is undefined. It may give the correct output, crash, or do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
const char* message = ("Some extra info \n" + errorMessage()).c_str();
```

errorMessage() will return a temporary std::string which will go out of scope before the next line runs.

I would suggest doing this instead:

```
std::string message = "Some extra info \n" + errorMessage();
```

Then when you need to pass a pointer to the underlying buffer you can use:

```
message.c_str();
```